# Could not find the program 'android-studio' error

Tags: manjaro

I am using manjaro OS KDE plasma on my Raspberry Pi 4b 8gb ram edition.
So now I am installing Android Studio. I download snapshot of Android Studio from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-studio/

The file is in .desktop format.

And then I tick on executable option in permissions from properties and then when I run it it show this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The `.desktop` file is a readable text file that allows GUI (Point and click) access to a program. It is NOT the program. Read the documentation.

Comment: I don't know how it'd work on Manjaro, but AUR packages are meant to be installed and on Arch you'd have to `git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/android-studio.git`, `cd android-studio` and run `makepkg -sri`. Installing the package also ensures `android-studio` gets a symbolic link in `/usr/bin`, which most likely is in your PATH - this a necessary condition not to incur in a "program not found" error.

Comment: Ok thanks for it i will try this. But when i use commands on this they don't work because I am using raspberry pi so the structure of my raspberry is arm so android studio is supported arm structures but it support arm 64 but in commands it always show application is not for arm.  Thank you for comments i will try this

Comment: Actually installing application with commands are don't work as same like actual hardware on Raspberry pi .

Comment: @Techlord Uh, sorry, I didn't think of that. Arch is x86_64 only and the packaged software assumes that architecture, including that in the AUR. Also, x86_64 is the only architecture the Android Studio's [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) mentions with respect to Linux.